# Change default logo to .SVG image programatically

Tags: magento2, logo

Magento does not support loading svg through admin panel, so i am trying to change the website logo through code.

My logo is here:

```
public/app/design/frontend/Name/Name_theme/web/images/my-logo.svg
```

I changed the file name here:

```
public/app/design/frontend/Name/Name_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

it now looks like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">147</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">24</argument>
        <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/my-logo.svg</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I deleted the cache using the command:

```
rm -rf public/var/cache
```

But this does not seem to help and my logo is not displaying.

*Are there any other ways i can achieve this?*

Comment: Please post a question or translate in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of  language

Comment: @AmitBera we have successfully translated question

Comment: ha ha , You used google. I have wait for user  update

Comment: Yes @AmitBera used google translate :)

Comment: Just trying to help the new contributor to get their question answered :D

Comment: Ive been through to correct all the grammar also

Answer (score 2):

it is recomended do not change the vendor files so.
in default.xml file paste this code and create web/images/logo.png file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <action method="setLogoFile">
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">
                    images/logo.png
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

clean the cache and reload the page