# After Upgrade Magento ver. 2.4.3 Logo displayed Default Magento Logo : Magento 2.4.3

Tags: logo, magento2.4.3

**After Upgrade Latest Magento ver. 2.4.3** Logo displayed Default Magento Logo... Uploaded logo was not display in ***Magento 2.4.3***

***I have checked at: Magento Admin > Content > Design > Configuration > Defult Store View > Header > Logo Image. File is properly uploaded.***

Any One facing this Issue ?

***Note: Magento ver. 2.4.3***

Comment: have you ran deploy command in all databases? and cleared all magento cache?

Comment: yes all thing done

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unsure if you solved this in the end, but we had the same issue when upgrading from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3.

The issue for us was from some new logo arguments added to [default.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml) in 2.4.3:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logoPathResolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoPathResolver</argument>
        <argument name="logo_size_resolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoSizeResolver</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

As we were overriding default.xml in our theme these were missing. Adding these arguments to our theme default.xml solved it.

Comment: If you are encountering this default logo issue specifically on the "Print Order" page and are on M2.4.3 or M2.4.4, then checkout this know issue which is fixed in M2.4.5: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/34943

Answer (score 2):

Under www/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logoPathResolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoPathResolver</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_size_resolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoSizeResolver</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

And make sure to clear your cache and Fastly cache if you use it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with MGS template.
I followed advices on this thread [Change default logo to .SVG image programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246270/change-default-logo-to-svg-image-programatically) by adding below code to default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <action method="setLogoFile">
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">
                    images/logo.png
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/193514)

Comment: Sorry about that! I was using my phone and answered it instead of commenting. I updated the text with a real answer this time.

Comment: Great, it will help others..+1

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to different ways of calling the Magento 2.4.3 logo and the previous version.
I did override the theme follow path app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/Name_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
<arguments>
    <argument name="logoPathResolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoPathResolver</argument>
    <argument name="logo_size_resolver" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoSizeResolver</argument>
</arguments>
```

Comment: I done this however not i see empty space incited of logo.